# Upgrading from ParameterizedRowMapper to SingleColumnRowMapper for multiple columns

Tags: spring, repository

I'm upgrading a Spring 3 application to Spring 4. My [`@Repository`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Repository.html) has [`ParameterizedRowMapper`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/ParameterizedRowMapper.html) objects to map the SQL results to objects. But since Spring 4 that interface has been [deprecated](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/deprecated-list.html#interface) "in favor of the regular [`SingleColumnRowMapper`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/SingleColumnRowMapper.html)". But I use mappers for mapping **multiple** columns. How am I meant to map multiple columns using `SingleColumnRowMapper`? Or am I meant to be doing something completely different?

For example, here is the kind of code I have now:

```
    private static final ParameterizedRowMapper<Thing> THING_ENTRY_MAPPER = new ParameterizedRowMapper<Thing>() {

       @Override
       public Thing mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
          return new Thing(rs.getLong(1), rs.getLong(2), rs.getInt(3));
       }
    };


    @Override
    public List<Thing> getThings(
          ID id, long start, long end) {
       final Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>(4);
       putIDParams(params, id);
       putTimeRangeParams(params, start, end);
       return getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().query(QUERY_THING, params,
             THING_ENTRY_MAPPER);
    }
```

How should I be implementing that kind of functionality now?

Comment: Hmm not sure why it is in there but I'm sure it is a typo. It should be the regular [`RowMapper`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowMapper.html) instead. Since Spring 3.x that is parameterized and as such the `ParameterizedRowMapper` is obsolete.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6960542/parameterizedrowmapper-is-recommended-or-rowmapper

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Javadoc seems to be wrong. The Spring Framework designers probably intend use of the `RowMapper<Thing>` interface to replace `ParameterizedRowMapper<Thing>`. That is, use the base interface.